# "Package 'dconf-cli' has no installation candidate"

Tags: apt

I want to be able to colour my gnome terminal (on Debian), using this [package](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized), and the installation notes require me to first execute `sudo apt-get install dconf-cli`, but doing so gives me an error.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dconf-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dconf-cli' has no installation candidate
```

I cannot even find the package on the synaptic package manager. How can I install this? I ran `apt-cache policy dconf-cli` as well:

```
 apt-cache policy dconf-cli 
 dconf-cli: 
 Installed: (none) 
 Candidate: (none) 
 Version table:
```

Comment: What Debian version? the `dconf` commandline tool is provided by package `dconf-tools` in earlier versions, I think

Comment: @steeldriver,  cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons:

1. You are using Debian stable (Wheezy) in which case [the package is just not available to you](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/d-conf). In this case you either [add the repositories](https://serverfault.com/a/382101/180142) or upgrade your system to Jessie. This is the most likely reason.
2. You are using testing (Jessie)/unstable in which case without the `main` section or with obsolete package lists. Check that you have a line with either `testing main` or `unstable main` (you can replace testing with jessie) and run `apt-get update` to make sure your list is actual. Change the mirror if that doesn't work.

I would upgrade to Jessie since the release date is near anyways.

---

The binary you are looking for was possibly provided by dconf-tools before:

```
d-conf (0.16.0-2) experimental; urgency=low

  [ Sebastien Bacher ]
  * debian/control.in, debian/dconf-editor.install, 
    debian/dconf-cli.install, debian/dconf-tools.install:
    - split dconf-tools in dconf-cli and dconf-editor, the dconf command
      line utility is used outside GNOME/GTK environments and shouldn't 
      require gtk. Keep the dconf-tools binary as a transitional one so
      users upgrading still have the editor.

 [...]


 -- Sebastien Bacher <seb128@debian.org>  Fri, 31 May 2013 17:48:50 +0100
```

Comment: I am a little bit hesitant to upgrade to an unstable version because I am too inexperienced to deal with possible issues myself. This was necessary for me to install a gnome-terminal color theme, which might have been nice, but they all seem to require the dconf-cli, I can live without it