# Likewise-open for Ubuntu 14.04 Not available?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I have found references to this issue around, but nowhere seems to post a solution that works for me.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install likewise-open
```

However this returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package likewise-open is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libwbclient0:i386 libwbclient0

E: Package 'likewise-open' has no installation candidate
```

I am just wondering if anyone has managed to get this working on 14.04 Or there are any alternatives for connecting to a Windows domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Package 'dconf-cli' has no installation candidate"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175307/package-dconf-cli-has-no-installation-candidate)

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen for details on Likewise Open's replacement.